# cannot install application from source using tar.gz archive

Tags: installation, tar, gzip

I tried to install utimer (https://launchpad.net/utimer) by following the below steps.

```
$ tar -zvxf utimer-0.4.tar.gz
$ cd utimer-0.4
/utimer-0.4$ ./configure
/utimer-0.4$ ls 
aclocal.m4  autogen.sh  config.h.in  configure     COPYING  depcomp   INSTALL     Makefile.am    Makefile.in  mkinstalldirs  po      README.in
AUTHORS     ChangeLog   config.log   configure.ac  data     Doxyfile  install-sh  Makefile.decl  missing      NEWS           README  src
/utimer=0.4$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.
```

How shall I proceed?

Also tried,

```
/utimer-0.4$ ./autogen.sh
========= Preparing uTimer ============
======== Running autoreconf ===========
./autogen.sh: line 3: autoreconf: command not found
```

Installed autoconf. It installed 4 new packages - `autoconf` `automake` `autotools-dev` `m4`

But I get another error.

```
========= Preparing uTimer ============
======== Running autoreconf ===========
Can't exec "libtoolize": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/autoreconf line 196.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/bin/autoreconf line 196.
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
aclocal: couldn't open directory `m4': No such file or directory
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

How should one proceed when 'makefile' is not generated?

Thanks.

Comment: What should I do when make file is not created? It was my guess that autoconf will work (i don't even know what it is). Is it the correct way to proceed when make doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try install autoreconf by following:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Comment: tried. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

(for `libtoolize`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing an answer, but can you please explain why this particular package is needed here?